# executeScript / insertCSS fails when frameId set

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am working on a background chrome extension and have found that I cannot insert js or css into a specific frame. As per the current chrome.tabs API documentation https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-executeScript:

> If allFrames is true, implies that the JavaScript or CSS should be injected into all frames of current page. By default, it's false and is only injected into the top frame. If true and frameId is set, then the code is inserted in the selected frame and all of its child frames.

I DO have a valid frameId to use in the call, but regardless of whatever is set in `details.frameId`, the call fails with the following error:

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, {
    code: 'document.body.style.backgroundColor="red"',
    allFrames: true,
    frameId: frameId
});
```

`Error: Invalid value for argument 2. Property 'frameId': Unexpected property.`

Setting `frameId = 0` (always a valid frame - the top frame) still fails. I have to REMOVE the `frameId` property for the `executeScript` or `insertCSS` to succeed. Is this documented feature not actually implemented?

Comment: You'll have to add the code you are having throw the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After further research, as Rob W stated, the documentation is wrong... `frameId` support for `executeScript` and `insertCSS` is **NOT** supported in Chrome 39 as the documentation states. It is not supported as of the current release of Chrome 49 (49.0.2623.110).

I have successfully got them to work in the current canary release of Chrome (51.0.2699.0).

**Update:** Chrome 50.0.2661.75 supports `frameId` in both `executeScript` and `insertCSS`.

Comment: Chrome 50.0.2661.75 was released today. It supports frameId as documented in both executeScript and insertCSS.

Answer (score 1):

Seems this is a bug and is supposed to be fixed in Chrome 50, according to the bug report:
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=63979

Comment: This is not a bug, the feature was only implemented in Chrome 51. The "Since Chrome 39" label in the documentation is just wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Based on this [github page](https://github.com/Rob--W/chrome-api/tree/master/chrome.tabs.executeScriptInFrame), you need to add the `chrome.tabs.executeScriptInFrame` method to the `chrome.tabs API`. This method allows one to run a content script in the context of a frame, instead of all frames within a tab, via the frameId parameter.

The method follows the same syntax as `chrome.tabs.executeScript,` except that the first argument (specified by the InjectDetails type) is extended with the frameId property. Since `frameId` makes no sense without a `tabId`, the `tabId` parameter is required.

> NOTE: You can't execute the `chrome.tabs.executeScript` in a frame if
>   you don't have host permission for the top frame.

Comment: Thanks abielita - I am aware of this method written by a 3rd party to extend the chrome.tabs API. I was just wondering on the native - and documented - feature of the API. I have opened an issue with Chromium.org to assist in resolution. I will advise on their answer.